# How to approximate Heaviside function by finite difference?

Tags: numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-difference-methods

I want to write the numerical scheme of
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \alpha \Delta u - u H(u - u_c)+f(x,y,t)
\end{equation*}
Where $H$ is a Heaviside function and $u_c$ is a constant. I want to write its numerical scheme by Implicit method.

I wrote the scheme for
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \alpha \Delta u +f(x,y,t)
\end{equation*}

I don't know how to approximate Heaviside function by finite difference. Can any one suggest some notes or idea how to solve this with Heaviside function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finite differences are used to approximate derivatives, not functions. A fully implicit scheme for your problem would be just
$$
\frac{u^{n+1} - u^n}{\Delta t} = \alpha \Lambda u^{n+1} - u^{n+1} H(u^{n+1} - u_c) + f^{n+1}.
$$

The problem is that now you have a nonlinear system of equations for $u^{n+1}$:
$$
u^{n+1} - \alpha \Delta t \Lambda u^{n+1} + \Delta t u^{n+1} H(u^{n+1} - u_c)
= u^n + \Delta t f^{n+1}. \tag{*}
$$
This might be a tough problem for nonlinear solver you're using for the problem.

To overcome the discontinuous nature of the Heaviside function you might replace it with a smooth analogous:
$$
H(u - u_c) \approx \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \tanh \frac{u - u_c}{\delta}\right).
$$
Parameter $\delta$ controls the approximation quality: for smaller values of $\delta$ approximation is better, but the nonlinear problem $(*)$ becomes much harder.

Maybe you don't need  a fully implicit scheme and
$$
\frac{u^{n+1} - u^n}{\Delta t} = \alpha \Lambda u^{n+1} - u^{n+1} H(u^n - u_c) + f^{n+1}.
$$
might work. This scheme leads to a **linear** problem for $u^{n+1}$
$$
u^{n+1} - \alpha \Delta t \Lambda u^{n+1} + \Delta t u^{n+1} H(u^{n} - u_c)
= u^n + \Delta t f^{n+1}, \tag{**}
$$
but it might be oscillating or unstable when the numerical solution approaches $u_c$.